# var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); doesnt get the email but gets an empty string

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

So my code suppose to make me a tracking sheet of edits on the main sheet but when its gets the email it gives an empty email unless its my main email then its works for some reason
here is the main function.
and my friend from his pc it didnt even got "" the script didnt run so irdk the problems.
btw i am new to this so dont make fun of me please.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Check if the event object is defined
  if (!e || !e.source) {
    // If the event object is not defined or does not have 'source' property, exit the function
    return;
  }

  var ss = e.source; // Get the active spreadsheet
  var trackingSheetUrl = "Url here"; // Put the URL of your tracking sheet here
  var trackingSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(trackingSheetUrl);
  var trackingSheet = trackingSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0]; // Assuming the tracking sheet is the first sheet

  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); // Get the email of the user who made the change
  if (user == ""){
    user = "error";
  }
  var userLocation = searchDataColumnWithUser(trackingSheetUrl, user);
  if (userLocation) {
    // User found, increment the value
    var currentValue = userLocation.getValue();
    userLocation.setValue(currentValue + 1);
  } else {
    // User not found, create new row
    var lastUserRow = trackingSheet.getLastRow();
    var newUserRow = lastUserRow + 1;
    trackingSheet.getRange(newUserRow, 1).setValue(user); // Set username
    trackingSheet.getRange(newUserRow, 2).setValue(1);    // Set initial value as 1
    trackingSheet.getRange(newUserRow, 2).setValue(1);    // Set initial value as 1
  }
}
```

To get the email of the user who edited.

Comment: Does your friend have access to the tracking sheet as well as your main csheet?

Comment: @J.G. not to the tracking sheet but i used my alts they dont have access aswell to the tracking sheet and still get an empty user instead of full email

Comment: He'lll never be able to run a script to modify a file he doesn't have access to. But that is besides the point because of onEdit restrictions, see below.

Comment: It it is going to be hard for people to answer your question in its current state. Please add some context for what you are trying to achieve, any libraries/packages you are using to do so, and review the grammar/punctuation of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the onEdit restrictions. There are some limitations you might be running into.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Specifically I think your problem is:

> They can modify the file they are bound to, but cannot access other
> files because that would require authorization.
>
> They may or may not be able to determine the identity of the current
> user, depending on a complex set of security restrictions.

Can you make your edit log a hidden tab in the same spreadsheet? That might solve your issues.

Incidentally there is a completely different api you should consider using, since all you want is a count of how many times other users changed your file.

https://www.labnol.org/code/20060-monitor-file-changes-in-drive

Comment: i wanna use it with dates to see everyday how many changes each person did in the google sheet

Comment: i tried the hidden tab but still giving me ""